# npm run dev is not working. I get this error: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-run

I expected npm run dev to run my website locally. It usually works fine.

I keep getting this error: [MyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9z7e.png)

I have the latest versions of npm and node installed.
I tried deleting node_modules folder and then reinstalling, but that didn't work.
I tried clearing cache but that didn't work too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569907/error-in-react-vite-project-due-to-rollup-dependency-module-not-found)